# Windows batch Do was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, cmd

Can anyone please find here that why I am getting error "Do was unexpected at this time"?

```
echo
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do ( 
    S:
    cd \WRO_Regression_results\%%A

    FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
        SET b=%%i
        GOTO :found
    )
    echo No subfolder found
    goto :eof

    echo Most recent subfolder: %b%
    cd %b%
    dir

    find /c "O K" tooling.report
    if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
    echo found
    goto done

    :notfound
    echo notfound
    goto done

    :done   
)

pause
```

Comment: you have a `goto :found`, but I don't see the `:found` label.?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that you're attempting to define labels within the FOR loop. This is probably not allowed (though I know of no definitive reference for CMD syntax). Here's a slightly modified version of your script (with `:found` defined).

```
echo
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do ( 
    S:
    cd \WRO_Regression_results\%%A

    FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
        SET b=%%i
        GOTO :found
    )
    echo No subfolder found
    goto :eof

    echo Most recent subfolder: %b%
    cd %b%
    dir
)

:found
find /c "O K" tooling.report
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo found
goto done

:notfound
echo notfound
goto done

:done   


pause
```

If you wanted found and notfound to execute for every item in the loop, you could do something like this. Delayed expansion is necessary to access variables that change within the FOR loop(s). CALL can be used to treat labels like subroutines. AFAIK, there's no way to break out of a FOR loop in CMD, so the FOUND variable is a sentinel value that prevents `b` from being set after the first iteration through the loop. If you describe the expected behavior of your script, I would have a better idea how to achieve the desired goal.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

echo for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (myfile.txt) do ( 
    S:
    cd \WRO_Regression_results\%%A

    SET FOUND=0
    FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
        IF NOT !FOUND!==1 (
            SET b=%%i
            SET FOUND=1
        )
    )
    IF !FOUND!==1 (CALL :found) ELSE (CALL :notfound)

    echo Most recent subfolder: %b%
    cd %b%
    dir )

:found
find /c "O K" tooling.report
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo found
EXIT /B

:notfound
echo notfound
EXIT /B


:done   


pause
```

Comment: If you wish to have the `:found` and `:notfound` targets within the loop, you'll probably have to do it with an `IF () THEN ELSE ()` statement. You didn't say exactly what the behavior was supposed to be, so I took a guess. It might be wrong.